# Double click disabled select box to enable

Tags: html, mouseevent, jquery

I'm trying to enable all form elements on double click of the form, and have simplified code as follows:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="foo" disabled />
    <select name="bar" disabled>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('form').dblclick(function() {
            $(this).find('input,select').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, the form double click event does not fire while hovering over the disabled `<select>` element. And unfortunately, the ["readonly" attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) does not work on `<select>` elements.

This is for an internal application, and I only need it function on Google Chrome.

**UPDATE:**

I'm getting a bunch of answers on this, and I think I need to revise my question to help guide the process... **What does the W3C spec on disabled form elements say?**... It appears the double click event doesn't fire on disabled `<input>` elements in Firefox for example. Perhaps the fact that it fires in Chrome is a bug/misalignment w/ spec that I can't count on always being there.

At the moment, watching for the double click event on an absolutely positioned wrapper element above the form seems like the best option... even though I hate adding extra wrapper elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YwvZV/)

```
$(function () {    
    $('form').dblclick(function () {
        $(this).find('input,select').removeProp('disabled').removeClass('no-pointer');
    }).find(':input').addClass('no-pointer');
});
```

CSS:

```
.no-pointer{pointer-events:none}
```

Comment: Interesting. This answers the question as stated best... however, what is the W3C spec for events disabled form elements? Perhaps, the double click event firing in Chrome on `<input>` elements is a bug?

Comment: @DavidBudiac that's true, maybe its a bug, in this case use ':input' not 'select' as selector to add class

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest putting a `div` overlaying the entire form, and place the click handler on that.  Disabled fields do not fire click handlers.

Comment: But the click handler is for the `form`, which is never disabled, just the fields within the form. Double clicking on the disabled text input works fine.,

Comment: @Bartdude -- I agree, I'm just wondering why the double click works on the disabled text input and not the `select`.

Comment: @tymeJV  I actually don't believe it works on a disable input either.  http://jsfiddle.net/TvBR6/4/  Though as is alluded to in the question, will work on a readonly input.  Though the handler is on the form, it does not register at all on the disabled elements so it cannot bubble to the form.

Comment: @JamesMontagne -- http://jsfiddle.net/sEMZX/ -- When you paste OP's code into it works on the text input, not the select.

Comment: @prrstn Ah, an absolutely positioned wrapper. That seems like the best option... didn't interpret that from James' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="foo" disabled/>
        <select name="bar" disabled>
            <option>a</option>
            <option>b</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#wrapper').dblclick(function() {
    $('form').find('input, select').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/TvBR6/3/

*(Just double-click the red div and take a look).*

Comment: Still fails if you double click the select.

Comment: I can figure out why that requirement is needed, I think a `double-click` event assigned to the `wrapper` div is enough.

Comment: Is this good UX? What about Accessibility? Why not use a button or checkbox? You might add a button additionally anyway, for those who can't double-click.

Comment: @Andrew It's for an internal app, so UX/Accessibilty isn't as huge of a concern as it normally would be. However, "click to edit" seems to be a regularly used practice.